# Combined Matrix from LHS to RHS

Tags: matrix

I am rotating an 3D object around a point that is not the origin.
To do this I perform this I create a combined matrix transform by following https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/affine/aroundPoint/

[R] = [T]-1 * [R0] * [T]

This was done in a Left Hand system.
What do I need to do to [R] to use it in a Right Hand system (basically Blender)?

Comment: The basic operation-- translate to pivot point, rotate, untranslate-- doesn't depend on handedness of the coordinate system.  But the exact rotation matrix you use is dependent on handedness.  The same matrix will go in opposite directions depending on handedness.

Comment: @Nathan So if I just transpose the rotation part of the matrix (if I'm using 4x4, just transpose the 3x3 part), I should end up with the RHS version of it?

Comment: I believe so, yes.  Not an expert, just a bit of HLSL experience.  (I also misspoke above: the general procedure is translate pivot point to origin, rotate, untranslate.)